Do average native speakers understand the figurative meaning of 'lean in' which is 'to proactively take charge of a situation'?
I see that the literal meaning of 'lean in' is 'To shift one's weight forward; to lean forward or towards something' as defined in wiktionary.
Is the figurative meaning of 'lean in', which is 'to proactively take charge of a situation',
as defined in wiktionary, easily inferred or obvious from the literal meaning when it is heard first time?
And do average native speakers understand this figurative meaning?
I learned that it is from  Sheryl Sandberg's 2013 book Lean In: Women, Work, and the Will to Lead as explained in the freedictionary.
Thank you very much.

I am aware of it as an annoying Americanism. "Lean in," thanks to the title of a new book by Facebook COO Sheryl Sandberg, has become "the idiom of the moment," Motoko Rich writes in the New York Times, adding "the phrase seems to have taken on a life of its own." But where did all of this "leaning in" come from? Article at Vocabulary.com

Thank you for the comment, but what's with the downgrade?  I just want to know if the phrase is in wide currency.

Not my downvote.

Thank Michael for letting me know.

Unlikely.
That is a particular piece of imagery invented by the author, and having no real currency. I can find no examples that aren't from the author, or from others directly referencing her book.
But given context it is readily understandable.  In the examples, you see "not drop out but lean in...." So one immediately understands that the term is being used in contrast to "drop out".
Otherwise, no, this would not be understandable.

As a pillion passenger on a motorbike, obviously you don't get much control. But if you "lean in" to the curves, you can at least "share" control. "Leaning out" causes the exact opposite - you can't really compete with the inertia of the bike anyway, and it's tiresome for the rider if you're "fighting" his lean; that's partly why male bikers like a lightweight female pillion who clasps arms around the rider so as to exactly copy his moves. I doubt this particular figurative usage will have legs, though.

@FumbleFingers - I used to be a motorcyclist (although never a 'biker'; my last mount was a Velocette) and let me tell you, the one thing I used to tell pillion passengers was 'Let me do the leaning!'.

Thank you James K. for the answer. Then I guess Sheryl sort of invented a new meaning.  I always struggle to gain more fluency in English, and it is hard to know if a phrase like this is in wide currency.  Thank you FumbleFingers for the new phrase and word.

I never heard of OP's cited usage. Don't assume anything in wiktionary is credible.
The idiomatic standard for taking an unwelcome active role / control is muscle in.
For simply offering unwanted advice or opinions, it's  butt in  - which can also simply mean "join in an ongoing conversation" or "interrupt someone who is speaking" (neutrally, not necessarily unwelcome interference).

Thank you FumbleFingers for the comment.  It is not just in wiktionary.  It is also in https://www.merriam-webster.com/wordplay/words-were-watching-lean-in    and  https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/lean-in#:~:text=lean%20in-,phrasal%20verb,hard%20to%20do%20it%20successfully

I don't know who decides what to put in to oxfordlearnersdictionaries, but the sense you're asking about isn't in the full (subscription only) OED. Nor is it listed in M-W - your link is just to a discussion page. The only actual definition of to lean in I see in M-W is something different: to persevere in spite of risk or difficulty (also unknown to me -an Americanism?). You can think what you like about who should understand it, but even after writing all this, I assure you I won't be bothering to commit the usage to memory!

Thank you FumbleFingers for the comment.  I can save my time and space in my brain.  There is so much to learn for English, and I do not have room for such phrases.  Thank you.

"Don't assume anything in wiktionary is credible." Absolutely this.

@MichaelHarvey: I've just realised that my phrasing could have been better. I didn't mean "nothing in Wiktionary is credible", but that could be how the words are understood. Any randomly-selected item in Wiktionary is a darn site more likely to be something most native Anglophones would know of / agree with than a randomly-selected entry in Urban Dictionary
